# Android Trouble with cardElevation

Tags: android, android-elevation

I'm meeting a strange problem.

I've a XML like this :

- ScrollView

  - LinearLayout

    - CardView
    - CardView
    - CardView

On each cardView I set :

> app:cardElevation="2dp"

For the first & the second CardView I can see an elevation, but it fails for the third, why ?

EDIT, the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/XXXX"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:res="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/matchParent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/wrapHeight"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                style="@style/wrapHeight"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/wrapHeight"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <> .... </>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                style="@style/wrapHeight"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/wrapHeight"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <> .... </>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                style="@style/wrapHeight"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/wrapHeight"
                    android:orientation="vertical">                 
                    <> .... </>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide your xml

Comment: @deveLost are you solve your problem?

Comment: I added margin on each cardView, and it works.... I don't understand exaclty why...

Answer (score 0):

```
app:cardElevation="2dp"
```

your main problem is the above statement and moreover can I know what is your min and target sdk for the given app.

Comment: Min sdk : 14 / target : 22

Comment: This is the main reason it isnt working....
**CardView was introduced in the support library for the Android L preview, at the start**

Comment: target 22 = Android L 5.1 ... And it works, because I'm using it in recyclerview with cardview, and no problem.

Comment: It would be better, if you would use any drawable xml to show this property.... 
Because even before this feature was introduced WhatsApp n other app used to showcase this property.

Comment: This is the only possible solution to ur question ... **refer to this link for more help** [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

Comment: Mhh I don't understand exactly why it will work properly with recyclerview, and no with that....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this.

In your Linear layout- add marginBottom greater than your elevation,

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

I assume - your linear layout hides your last element elevation.